# How to push a new element into an array inside a mongo doc using `update`?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

The docs for nodejs mongodb driver's [`update`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/reference/ecmascript6/crud/#updating-documents) function say that the second argument is an "`update document`", but don't describe what one of those is.

They show an example of how to use this to set a root node value in a document:

`var r = yield col.updateOne({a:1}, {$set: {b: 1}});`

This sets the `item.b` of the document with `item.a===1` to 1.

... but I can't extrapolate from here to see how to add an element to an array that is a leaf (not at the root of the item like `b` above)

This could be

`col.updateOne({a:1}, {$push: {sub_node: {the_list: 1}}});`

or

`col.updateOne({a:1}, {sub_Node: {this_list: {$push: 1}});`

... what's the actual way?

---

And (side question) where is this documented?  How do we know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There appears to be no information about how the nodejs mongodb driver implements the `update` document, within the nodejd mongodb driver reference.

It also appears that the native (mongo) implementation works.   This is documented [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/).

Accessing nested document elements is done using the "dot notation"

```
theDb.collection('projects').updateOne({id: projectId}, {$push: {"contract.variations": variationId}})
```

---

This is unintuitive for a `react` developer, where the `immutability-helper` has an `update` that looks deceptively similar, but uses the nested object syntax for this.  Pity!

Answer (score 1):

You can use two operators 
1) $push

```
col.updateOne({a:1}, {$push: {sub_node: {the_list: 1}}})
```

This will push the the_list variable inside a sub_node object array object

2)$addToSet:

```
col.updateOne({a:1}, {$addToSet: {sub_node: {the_list: 1}}})
```

This will also do the same thing as $push but it will avoid duplicate entry inside sub_node array
You can see mongodb documentation

Comment: Thanks!  That appears to be exactly what I need, of course.  Where are these operators documented?

Comment: I found the doco, in the mongo (not nodejs mongodb) documentation, here:  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/

Comment: Turns out this answer is wrong.   "[To specify a `field` in an embedded document or in an array, use dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#up._S_push)"